# How to add HTTP request header in camel exchange object while calling soap service?

Tags: java, soap, apache-camel, soap-client

At soap service side below is the code

```
Map http_headers = (Map) mctx.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
List userList = (List) http_headers.get("Username");
List passList = (List) http_headers.get("Password");
```

During exchange the code I have added at the client using apache camel

```
Exchange exchangeRequest = lProducerTemplate.request(endpoint,
        new Processor() {
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                exchange.getIn().setBody(payload);
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, headers);
}});
```

When I tried to see packet using wireshark I see that nothing gets added to the header(both soap or http)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to set a map to a single header. I think you may be looking for

```java
Exchange exchangeRequest = lProducerTemplate.request(endpoint,
    new Processor() {
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

            exchange.getIn().setBody(payload);
            exchange.getIn().setHeaders(headers);
}});
```